# Conditionally update the value in column using lag value

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, group-by

I am trying to update the value in a `RAIN` column in following dataframe using `ifelse` condition. If value of `RAIN` is less than value of `RAIN` from previous row then replace that value with value from previous row. The sample dataframe is as below:

```
TRGCODE    gr      DATE      TIME     RAIN
   12      24   2017-03-15   1645     00
   12      24   2017-03-15   1700     00
   12      24   2017-03-15   1715     0.5
   12      24   2017-03-15   1730     00
   12      24   2017-03-15   1745     0.5
   12      24   2017-03-15   1800     0.5
   12      24   2017-03-15   1815     00
   12      24   2017-03-15   1830     00
   12      24   2017-03-15   1845     0.5
   12      24   2017-03-15   1900     00
   12      24   2017-03-15   1915     00
   12      24   2017-03-15   1930     0.5
   12      24   2017-03-15   1945     0.5
```

I tried with

```
df <- df %>% group_by(TRGCODE, gr) %>% dplyr::mutate(RAIN = ifelse(RAIN < lag(RAIN, default = first(RAIN)), lag(RAIN), RAIN))
```

But it's not the working the way I want (It will change value only for time 1730, 1815, 1900 and not for 1830 & 1915). The desired output is like:

```
TRGCODE    gr      DATE      TIME     RAIN
   12      24   2017-03-15   1645     00
   12      24   2017-03-15   1700     00
   12      24   2017-03-15   1715     0.5
   12      24   2017-03-15   1730     0.5
   12      24   2017-03-15   1745     0.5
   12      24   2017-03-15   1800     0.5
   12      24   2017-03-15   1815     0.5
   12      24   2017-03-15   1830     0.5
   12      24   2017-03-15   1845     0.5
   12      24   2017-03-15   1900     0.5
   12      24   2017-03-15   1915     0.5
   12      24   2017-03-15   1930     0.5
   12      24   2017-03-15   1945     0.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one potential solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "TRGCODE    gr      DATE      TIME     RAIN
   12      24   2017-03-15   1645     00
   12      24   2017-03-15   1700     00
   12      24   2017-03-15   1715     0.5
   12      24   2017-03-15   1730     00
   12      24   2017-03-15   1745     0.5
   12      24   2017-03-15   1800     0.5
   12      24   2017-03-15   1815     00
   12      24   2017-03-15   1830     00
   12      24   2017-03-15   1845     0.5
   12      24   2017-03-15   1900     00
   12      24   2017-03-15   1915     00
   12      24   2017-03-15   1930     0.5
   12      24   2017-03-15   1945     0.5",
   header = TRUE)

df %>%
  group_by(TRGCODE, gr) %>%
  mutate(RAIN = cummax(RAIN))
#> # A tibble: 13 × 5
#> # Groups:   TRGCODE, gr [1]
#>    TRGCODE    gr DATE        TIME  RAIN
#>      <int> <int> <chr>      <int> <dbl>
#>  1      12    24 2017-03-15  1645   0  
#>  2      12    24 2017-03-15  1700   0  
#>  3      12    24 2017-03-15  1715   0.5
#>  4      12    24 2017-03-15  1730   0.5
#>  5      12    24 2017-03-15  1745   0.5
#>  6      12    24 2017-03-15  1800   0.5
#>  7      12    24 2017-03-15  1815   0.5
#>  8      12    24 2017-03-15  1830   0.5
#>  9      12    24 2017-03-15  1845   0.5
#> 10      12    24 2017-03-15  1900   0.5
#> 11      12    24 2017-03-15  1915   0.5
#> 12      12    24 2017-03-15  1930   0.5
#> 13      12    24 2017-03-15  1945   0.5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This does not use the ifelse but it does the job you want

```
df<-structure(list(TRGCODE=c(12L,12L,12L,12L,12L,12L,12L,
                             12L,12L,12L,12L,12L,12L),gr=c(24L,24L,24L,24L,24L,
                                                           24L,24L,24L,24L,24L,24L,24L,24L),DATE=c("2017-03-15",
                                                                                                   "2017-03-15","2017-03-15","2017-03-15","2017-03-15","2017-03-15",
                                                                                                   "2017-03-15","2017-03-15","2017-03-15","2017-03-15","2017-03-15",
                                                                                                   "2017-03-15","2017-03-15"),TIME=c(1645L,1700L,1715L,1730L,
                                                                                                                                     1745L,1800L,1815L,1830L,1845L,1900L,1915L,1930L,1945L
                                                                                                   ),RAIN=c(0,0,0.5,0,0.5,0.5,0,0,0.5,0,0,0.5,0.5
                                                                                                   ),RAIN1=c(0,0,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,
                                                                                                             0.5,0.5)),row.names=c(NA,-13L),class="data.frame")

df$RAIN1<-df$RAIN
for(i in 2:nrow(df)) {
  if(df$RAIN1[i]<df$RAIN1[i-1])
    df$RAIN1[i]<-(df$RAIN1[i-1])
}
df

df$RAIN<-df$RAIN1
df$RAIN1<-NULL
df
```